# This page is not redirecting properly

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication

I used the following script from about.com:   http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/php_login_code_2.htm

The problem is that a few times it gives me this error:  The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
Code:

```
<?php

session_start(); 



// Process the POST variables
$username = $_SESSION["user_name"];
//$password = $_POST["password"];


    // Set up the session variables
     $_SESSION["user_name"] = $username;

       $ugh = $_REQUEST['url_name'];

          if($_POST){
           $_SESSION['user_name']=$_POST["user_name"];
          $_SESSION['password']=$_POST["password"];  
           }



              $secret = $info['password'];

            //Checks if there is a login cookie

            if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))


             //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page

                { 
           $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

            $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT user_name, password 
            FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username' 
            and url_name='$ugh'")or die(mysql_error());

          while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )) 



          {

               if (@ $info['password'] != $pass) 
                {

                    }

                  else

                 {

                  header("Location: home.php");



                  }

                     }

                     }


       //if the login form is submitted 

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted



         // makes sure they filled it in

             if(!$_POST['user_name'] | !$_POST['password']) {

    die('You did not fill in a required field.');

       }

// checks it against the database



if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

    $_POST['user_name'] = addslashes($_POST['user_name']);


}

$check = mysql_query("SELECT user_name,password 
    FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$_POST['user_name']."' 
    and url_name='".$ugh."'")or die(mysql_error());



         //Gives error if user dosen't exist

          $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

         if ($check2 == 0) {

           die('That user does not exist in our database. 
          <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');

            }

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  

            {

          $_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
          $_POST['password'] = $_POST['password'];



             //gives error if the password is wrong



           if (@ $_POST['password'] != $info['password']) {

            die('Incorrect password, please try again');


              }

              else 

             { 


          // if login is ok then we add a cookie 

         $_POST['user_name'] = stripslashes($_POST['user_name']); 

     $hour = time() + 3600; 

            setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['user_name'], $hour); 

            setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['password'], $hour);   



            //then redirect them to the members area 

           header("Location: home.php"); 

            } 

           } 

            } 

          else 

          {  



           // if they are not logged in 

           ?>
```

2nd code:

Then on each member page i use the following to make sure their login is correct:

```
      // Process the POST variables
       $email = $_SESSION["user_name"];


     // Set up the session variables
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $username;


   if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) { header("Location: log.php");}
```

Answer (score 2):

To paraphrase Blowski: http://kb.mozillazine.org/The_page_is_not_redirecting_properly

It's like firefox has reached it's maximum recursion depth: it has detected a seemingly endless loop of redirects

Answer (score 1):

What's the name of the files in the above scripts? If the name of the first script is home.php, then when a user visits home.php, it will keep reloading if the password is incorrect, so Firefox will return that message.

Alternatively, do you have anything in your .htaccess which is causing it?

Comment: the first stricpt is log.php.  htaccess has a file that takes the incoming username to display a page so imagine blowski.domain.com..

Comment: @KPO Hmm, can you post the contents of your .htaccess file as well? That is often the cause of faulty redirects.

Comment: @KPO I'm having real problems trying to debug the code, because there are quite a few bits that seem to be using global variables (or are actually errors). e.g. line 25: `$secret = $info['password'];` My suggestion would be to get it working with one URL, by removing .htaccess. Then when you know that's working with PHP, get a static version working with .htaccess. Then merge the two. Even better - try breaking this up into multiple functions so that you can test each bit of the code separately, rather than as one big block.

Comment: @blowski thanks.  Is there another script i can use.  I am too new to do the changes.  Thanks.

Comment: @KPO - The problem is that there is a lot of work that authentication has to do - your script above could very easily be hacked. I use a framework for all but the smallest of projects, and most frameworks will have authentication components or plugins which include security mechanisms. Try CodeIgniter, Yii, or CakePHP.

Comment: @blowski yeah this is a pretty unsecure script.  i am using for testing.  i will find/create a better one when i am ready to announce the service.  Explain to me something though, when somebody can hack your site, there is no one way it can be hacked, correct? because in the end its your code and validation.

Comment: @KPO Sorry not sure exactly what you mean. There are a lot of ways to hack. Secure your data before you do anything with it is the main rule. That's one of the advantages of a framework - they handle a lot of the security for you. Ideally, you should also harden your Apache with .htaccess.

Comment: I couldn't fix it at all.  been busy trying to figuring out.  planning on using a completely different script.

Comment: No problem i am looking to pay someone to come up with something robust.

Comment: @KPO Check out some of the frameworks as well - CodeIgniter, Symfony, CakePHP, Yii are all PHP frameworks with robust authentication systems that are basically plug-and-play. Personally, even if you pay someone, I would ask them to implement a framework instead of starting from scratch.